# Python Selenium: Unable to click inner link

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am automation a page in Python Selenium, after login I have to click a link named `Sales`, issue is link is enclosed a div hence not clickable. Here is the html:

```
<div class="NavItem hideIcon selected" data-nav="true"><a class="invoices" id="invoices" href="/go/invoices"><span class="label">Invoices</span></a></div>
```

I tried it as:

```
element_invoice_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "invoices")))
element_invoice_link.click()
```

It threw exception:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Answer (score 0):

try as follows

Find inner element:

```
element_invoice_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='invoices']/span")))
element_invoice_link.click()
```

Try different EC:

```
 element_invoice_link = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='invoices']/span")))
        element_invoice_link.click()
```

Check following:

1. Are there more elements with `Invoices` id?
2. Is the `Invoices` element visible in the GUI?

Comment: The issue is that page is not being loaded fully and it goes to access the element.

Comment: give more timeout as page loading itself takes time. so, it waits for more time to find the element.